# Highest Product of X Items

Tags: greedy-algorithms

**How do you find the highest product of *X* items?**

This should optimize for runtime complexity and protect from overflows from large products.

- *Inputs*

  1. An array of both positive and negative Ints representing potential products to the solution
  2. An Int representing the number of products required for the solution
- *Output*: An Int representing the highest product of *X* amount of numbers.

For example, for the *[highest product of 3 items](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCjDPGwCjCQ)*, the input is iterated through while updating the following variables. After the iteration has completed in $O(n)$ time, the *highest product of three* variable is returned as the solution.

- Lowest number
- Highest number
- Lowest product of two
- Highest product of two
- Highest product of three

Comment: Are the input numbers positive? Why isn't this just the product of the $X$ largest input numbers?

Comment: Steven, thanks for the comment. I've updated the post to indicate that the input can be both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let the integers be $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ sorted in decreasing order of magnitude, so $|a_1| \ge |a_2| \ge \cdots$, and suppose you want to find the product of $k$ of them that is as large as possible.

Then:

- If $a_1 \times \cdots \times a_k$ is positive, it is the solution.
- Otherwise, if $a_{k+1}$ is positive, the solution is $a_1 \times \cdots \times a_{k+1}$ (but omit $a_i$ from the product, where $a_i$ is the largest of the negative numbers in $a_1,\dots,a_k$, i.e., closest to zero).
- Otherwise, if $a_{k+1}$ is negative and at least one of $a_1,\dots,a_k$ is positive, the solution is $a_1 \times \cdots \times a_{k+1}$ (but omit the smallest positive number of $a_1,\dots,a_k$ from the product).
- Otherwise, if at least one of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is positive, the solution is $a_1 \times \cdots \times a_{k-1} \times a_j$ where $a_j$ is the largest positive number in $a_1,\dots,a_n$.
- If all of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are negative and $k$ is odd, then the solution is $a_{n-k+1} \times \dots \times a_n$.

This can be computed in $O(n \lg k)$ time using a heap of size $k$.

Comment: @Dmitry, good point!  I've revised my answer.  I hope I've covered all the cases now.

Answer (score 0):

**Time Complexity**: $O(nlogn)$

**Space Complexity**: $O(n)$

1. Sort the $input$ array.
2. If the last item is positive, find the product for the first $n$ items.
3. If the last item is negative, count how many $negativeItems$ exist up to $n$, and then round the number, $negativeItems$, down to the closest even number.
4. Starting with the smallest negative item, compare it to the largest item at the beginning of the $input$ array. Then compare the next largest negative item with the second-largest item, and so forth until all $negativeItems$ are compared.

   4a. Add the original value of the result of whichever number contains the greater absolute value into the $productArray$.

   4b. Add the remaining positive items, $n - negativeItems$, to the $productArray$.
5. Calculate the product from the $productArray$.